# jQuery pendulum not working in ie9

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9, transform, css-transforms

I have been looking down to a **pendulum in html5 and jquery**, i found this example on a website...

http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/jquery-pendulum-animation-pivot-point/

I embedded with customization to my website, i have read the documentation of this mentioning that **this will not work on Ie8 and older versions of firefox and safari**, after arranging all my UI together, it seems to be a problem with it in **IE9**...

I dnt know what but the example is working not my demo...

**Example:-**

http://www.webdevdoor.com/demos/html5-pendulum-demo/

**My demo:-**

http://jsfiddle.net/sZzy6/2/

**Screenshot:-**

[image: Ie9 demo]

**My JS:-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rotation = 7;
    var swingtime = 1603;
    var swinger = $('.pendulum-parent');

function init() {
            swinger.animate({rotate: rotation}, 0, function () {
                swinger.css("display", "block");
                rotation *= -1;
                pendulumswing1();
            });
}
function pendulumswing1() {
            swinger.animate({rotate: rotation},swingtime, "swing", function(){
                 rotation *= -1;
                 pendulumswing1();
            });
        }
init();

    });
```

Any solution for the above? Where i have been mistaken? or its an OS or Browser issue?

Comment: I would double check that your IE9 instance isn't running in IE8 compatibility mode, or something like that.

Comment: @autibyte yes, it's working in IE-10 and IE-9, But not working in IE-8,IE-7 and IE-10 compatibility mode.

Comment: Works for me in IE9 too. Your probelm seems really localized too your computer (OS/softawre/hardware maybe). Have you tested it on other computer?

Comment: Just to be sure what is your IE version from About Internet Explorer in Tools. Follow the instructions given here http://www.enable-javascript.com/ to verify JavaScript is working. Also try browsing with anti-virus/addons disabled so that it does not interfere with JavaScripts on JSfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you've already fixed this however both the jsfiddle and the demo website work in IE9. I am running this in IE10 however the browser mode should perfectly emulate the CSS and JavaScript capabilities. This might point to an external problem with your browser.

[Also here's a slight simplification of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUJhQ/1/)

```
$(function(){   

    var rotation = 7;
    var swingtime = 1603;
    var swinger = $('.pendulum-parent');
    swinger.css("display", "block");

    function pendulumSwing(first) {
        swinger.animate({rotate: rotation},swingtime, first? 0 : "swing", function(){
                 rotation *= -1;
                 pendulumSwing();
            });
        }
    pendulumSwing(true);

});
```

And a screen shot we can see it does in fact work.
[image]

Comment: hi thanks for reply, i am using ie9, but fiddle demo is not at all working in both ie9 and ie10 compatibility mode.... your mentioned fiddle demo is also not working in ie9...

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working as you provided it.

I'm using **Internet Explorer 10 with IE9 Browser mode** and it works fine.

Here's a screenshot of the pendulum working just clicking on the **Run** option:

[image: jQuery Pendulum on IE10 with IE9 Browser mode]

Comment: is this screenshot from IE9..??

Comment: Internet Explorer 10 with IE9 Browser mode as I said on the original answer

Comment: i am using ie9, its not working at all, i cnt find the reason why its nt working...